# TemplateDoesNotExist & {% extends "base.html" %} error

Tags: django, django-templates, extends

I'm having an issue that I personally have been unable to resolve and I think the easiest way to ask for help is to [link to the github folder where the error references](https://github.com/DylanAlloy/propaganda/tree/master/src) I've been pushing to and include this screenshot.

[image: templatedoestnotexist error screenshot]

I've looked at the other questions with very similar context and I've actually tried almost every single thing I've found. Some of it was related to project structure, some of it related to syntax or logic but I cannot find any such problem in my code and as a result, I've also probably added things/changed things that I didn't need to.

It's a sign I need help with the problem.

Comment: Do any of your templates load properly?

Comment: Yeah, all of them except for "panel.html", "activate.html"

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being a bizarre browser/django/cache issue involved with a corrupted project. The power went out where I'm working from the day I posted this and something must have happened that didn't lead me toward the answer but didn't prevent me from using the same project instance altogether.

If you run into something like this, I guess the answer is to have a backup.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise moving your `templates` folder to one of your apps, probably `redditpanel` in this case. I suspect that since they are in the root project folder Django is having a hard time finding them.

What I usually have is this structure:

```
- project (root folder)
|- app_x
 |- views.py
 |- templates
   |- template_x.html
|- app_y
 |- views.py
 |- templates
   |- template_y.html
|- project
 |- settings.py
```

This way, in each app's view you can reference the template directly and Django will search in this app's `template` folder, e.g.:

```
# in "app_x" views.py
class MyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'my_view.html'

# then, in "app_x"'s template folder you can create "my_view.html" file to be used in this view
```

Could you try this out and tell us the results?

Comment: I did try this already at one point but I've done it again and gotten the same error I had the first time I tried it. My problem stems mainly from the fact that this all began happening when I decided to rename the now-called "redditpanel" app 2 days ago, that's it. Before that (3 days ago) it was working fine. The error now is: http://i.imgur.com/vdDW8g9.png. ---https://github.com/DylanAlloy/propaganda/commit/0b48f1a5639eb71551e5b10b6fb5afcd1dec9430 this is the last version working with no major code differences whatsoever. This is now down to the fact that I have folders in different places.